# How to unmarshal a []byte into a json structure that is stored as a value inside a variable of type string?

Tags: go, marshalling, unmarshalling

Note: myjsonstruct is stored and read from a database. Hardcoding for clarity

```
myjsonstruct := `{"fldA":"", "fldB":"", "fldC":""}`

targetJsonString := `{"fldA":"valueA","fldB":"valueB","fldC":"valueC","fldOther":"valueOther"}`
```

Now, i want to unmarshal `targetJsonString` into `myjsonstruct` so that corresponding fields in `myjsonstruct` get populated.

Please note: myjsonstruct is a "string" and cannot be programmed in the code. I dont know this structure at the time of coding. it will be read as a string during runtime, perhaps from a database.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer this, https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Intersection of JSON strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690337/intersection-of-json-strings/52692253#52692253). Not an exact duplicate, but the same technique can be applied here as well.

Comment: @icza Thanks! this does exactly what I needed.

Comment: @icza this one worked, but for the array part inside a json, i had to write a lot of custom code. I am trying to figure out if there is an easier way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type myjsonstruct struct {
    FldA string `json:"fldA"`
    FldB string `json:"fldB"`
    FldC string `json:"fldC"`
}

func main() {
    targetJsonString := `{"fldA":"valueA","fldA":"valueB","fldA":"valueC","fldOther":"valueOther"}`

    res := &myjsonstruct{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(targetJsonString), res); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    myjsonstructBytes, err := json.Marshal(res)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(myjsonstructBytes))
}
```

It will print:
`{"fldA":"valueC","fldB":"","fldC":""}`

In playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qUkGAmvsmAD

`(!)` Also note, that fields in `myjsonstruct` must be public (start from capital letter), otherwise unmarshaller will not be able to access those fields.

Comment: We don't know the json structure at the time of coding. Thanks for the above code anyways.